# TabBar with center button

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

[image]

Hi, I'd like to make a tabBar with center button. As we can see from the image, when I clicked the tabbar, it will show me a view to select buttons. When I clicked the "notes" button, the view will disappear and my app will jump to the correspond viewcontroller and the tabbar.selectIndex = 2. I already made a subclass of UITabBarController, and add a button to the view, the code is like this [self.view addSubview:middleButton]. **Now the problem is, when I push viewcontroll, the tabbar disappear while the center button still on the page. And when I go back to the main viewcontroller, the tabbar will overlap the center button.** I don't want to make a whole custom UITabBarViewController, please tell me how to hide the center button when push viewcontroll and how to show it on the tapbar when I go back to the main viewcontroller.

Hi, Hament, I have not use method "-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item". My code is as below:

```html
@implementation MyTabBarController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [self setupViews];
    [self setupTabBarItems];
    [self setupMiddleButton];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)setupViews
{
    mask = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([MyMiddleButtonMask class]) owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    mask.delegate = self;
}
-(void)setupTabBarItems
{
    UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc1Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
    
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc2Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];   
    
    UIViewController *vc3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc3Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc3];    
    
    UIViewController *vc6 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc6Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc6];    
    
    UIViewController *vc7 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc7Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc7];     
    
    self.viewControllers = @[vc1Nav, vc2Nav, vc3Nav, vc6Nav, vc7Nav];
}
-(void)setupMiddleButton
{
    middleButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -16, 64, 64)];
    CGRect f = middleButton.frame;
    f.origin.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - f.size.height;
    f.origin.x = (SCREEN_WIDTH - f.size.width)/2;
    middleButton.frame = f;
    [middleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    
    middleButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    middleButton.layer.cornerRadius = middleButton.frame.size.height/2;
    [self.view addSubview:middleButton];
    
    [middleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didClickedMiddleButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
-(void)didClickedMiddleButton:(id)sender
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view addSubview:mask];
}

#pragma mark - KGOMiddleButtonMaskDelegate, Button1,2,3 are on the mask page.
-(void)didClickedButton1:(KGOMiddleButtonMask *)maskView
{
    self.viewControllers = @[vc1Nav, vc2Nav, vc3Nav, vc6Nav, vc7Nav];
    self.selectedIndex = 2;
    [maskView removeFromSuperview];
}
-(void)didClickedButton2:(KGOMiddleButtonMask *)maskView
{
    self.viewControllers = @[vc1Nav, vc2Nav, vc4Nav, vc6Nav, vc7Nav];
    self.selectedIndex = 2;
    [maskView removeFromSuperview];
}
-(void)didClickedButton3:(KGOMiddleButtonMask *)maskView
{
    self.viewControllers = @[vc1Nav, vc2Nav, vc5Nav, vc6Nav, vc7Nav];
    self.selectedIndex = 2;
    [maskView removeFromSuperview];
}
-(void)didClickedSelf:(KGOMiddleButtonMask *)maskView
{
    [maskView removeFromSuperview];
}
-(void)didClickedCloseButton:(KGOMiddleButtonMask *)maskView
{
    [maskView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: If you are adding button manually via [self.view addSubview:middleButton].
Then you have to remove button via removeFromSuperView in tab viewwilldissapear method.

Comment: Hi, Hament, thank you so much for replying me. I did so, when pushViewController, the tabbar disappeared, but it won't call the viewWillDisappear method. I don't know why.

Comment: is your tabBarController:didSelectViewController: selector delegate called?

Comment: Hi, Hament, I have not use method "-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item". And I have posted my code in the description panel.

Comment: How u are pushing to notes view controller?

Comment: Hi, Hament. I add this in BaseNavigationController. -(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.viewControllers.count)
    {
        viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145000/discussion-between-hament-miglani-and-emma).